# Multiple calls for mutiple Facebook, twitter buttons

Tags: facebook, twitter

If a page has multiple facebook/twitter buttons for multiple stories (24 buttons for 24 stories), its creating 24 files for fb likes and 24 folders for twitter where count is saved. This is making the page heavy unnecessarily. Can we store it in single file? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start using [css sprits](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), this allows you to load one image file and with css display only the section of the image that you need.

```
img.home {
    width:46px;
    height:44px;
    background:url(img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
}
```

In the example above you see that starting at position *0x0* in the image we display a rectangle *46px x 44px*.

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead. (But +1 for a good answer nonetheless).

Comment: Good point @JohnConde, I've changed the reference.